# what is the plug-in for Firefox in order to access the HP blade center

Tags: linux, java, hp, firefox, blade-server

I work with HP_blade center machine ,

Type - C7000 Enclosure G3

In the HP blade center I have couple of HW machines with Linux red-hat OS

I have successfully access to the HP integrated management center/module VIA address:

```
 https://192.23.4.56:443
```

- I access from the Firefox browser ( the last FireFox version ) , from WIN XP

But when I want to open the **console** ( in order to see the Linux OS screen )

I get the following: ( plug-in error )

[image]

**please advice how to download the plug-in in order to resolve this problem and from where?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the latest version of the Java Runtime Environment (JRE) from [java.com](http://java.com/en/).

Comment: Because I have VM machine , not with much resource - I can’t run the latest version ( double click on the JInstall.exe  - not really ran it )  , can I download old version ?  ( +1 for you  )

Comment: Give more resources to your VM. Most things should be able to run Java.